# Ubuntu detects that I don't have at least 4.4 GB free space, what should I do?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, hard-drive

When I try to install Ubuntu 12.04, it shows me, that I don't have at least 4.4 GB free space. How can I format my Hard Disk Drive?

Actually I have 8.4 GB free space, but I screwed up everything and reinstalled Ubuntu (12.04) so many times because it wasn't booting fine and now it shows me, that I can't install.

The problem is that the **"Continue"** button isn't available to be clicked.

Comment: Well, you really don't need to format your hdd, free up some space instead. But if you really do want to format, on the first screen of the installation process, click **"Try Ubuntu"**, and NOT "Install Ubuntu", then from the Dash, search for **GParted**, from there, you can format your hdd.

Comment: Can you mention on **which** and **How** much sized Partition do you want to install Ubuntu, do you have Other OS currently installed, how many partitions do you have. try to include as much info possible to get helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

To format the hard disk select `erase entire disc and install ubuntu` after selecting *install ubuntu*. This will erase and reformat the entire hard drive before installing Ubuntu.

If you want to install Ubuntu alongside windows,
you should load windows and delete some files (5-10gb minimum) to create space,
then defragment your hard drive before installing Ubuntu.

Comment: The problem is that The button: "Continue" isn't available to be clicked. :(

Comment: At what point / menu is the "continue" button not available?

Comment: Yes, the **"Continue"** would not be "clickable" since the Ubuntu Installer detects that you don't have enough space. That is why you have to click on **"Try Ubuntu"** first and use GParted to modify or format your partition(s).

Answer (score 0):

Formatting your hard drive will delete everything that is on it at the time. Is that really what you want to do?

Or is the problem that the installation is not reporting the correct amount of free space?

Since you don't have much free space, I assume that you already have Windows installed, and you are trying to install Ubuntu in dual-boot mode. Check your disk space in Windows: right-click on My Computer > Manage > Disk Management (underneath Storage) > physical disks are listed in the bottom of the middle frame, and each volume (partition) is listed in the top of the middle frame > note the Capacity and Free Space columns > how many drives do you have, and how much free space do they have?